# Pass parameter with json field when invoking POST in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have encountered an issue in `swift 3`:

I have an *API* which I need to access for data in my app, but the parameter that it demands is in the following format:

```
"jsonRequest" = {
                   "header" : "GetLocationListReq",
                   "accessKey" : "1234567890abcdefghij"
                }//this is in json format.
```

I tried to pass this parameter as *dictionary* to call the API, but at that point I obtained this message error:

```
Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed
```

Any one knows how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Would you mind sharing which _API_ (and method) you try to use so that we are able to help you better? My guess is that a Swift _dictionary_ is not the same as some kind of "json" representation (object).

Comment: These are headers I think? need to pass that in httpheaders maybe

Comment: @MuhammadRaza how do i do that? can you point me to a guide or something?

Comment: @progammingBeignner I post the answer, please check and let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass these things in header of the request.

for that you need to do like this

```
let headers = ["header": "GetLocationListReq",
              "accessKey": "1234567890abcdefghij"]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{
               r in
              //do what you want here 
}
```

hope this will work.

Comment: nope, they are not headers... If you are kind enough to help, i can pm you the keys and other things..

Answer (score 0):

try to post this  code

```
let par:[String:Any] = ["jsonRequest":[
            "header" : "GetLocationListReq",
            "accessKey" : "1234567890abcdefghij"
            ]]
```

pass it like that in Alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: par, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{
r in
//do what you want here 
}
```

Comment: Tried, it does not work... it get the error i pasted in the question .